# Window installer run two exe on single shortcut icon

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-installer

I have two .exe file that should run together otherwise my application won't work. So I created a batch script that can run two exe together ultimately it's batch window file not a window installer.

I looked into other packaging tool [Inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) but they not execute two thing parallel.

Anyway can I run two exe file with single shortcut icon from the window ? I would be grateful if you could give a little help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  But why not have one .exe launch the other one?

Comment: Is it possible ?  I am not tried yet this option cause two exe already build.

Comment: Yes I checked but batch file is not a solution cause I need to convert those into exe format. @elzooilogico

Comment: Yes @elzooilogico

Comment: If the other two executables are already built, you can easily build an executable that runs them both.  Depending on your circumstances, you may still need an installer to put the three executables in the right place and create a shortcut to the one that runs the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) resolved the issue and I went through the couple of it's own script which act on it's command. Here it's **setup.iss** the solution which worked :

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=Electron
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\MySetup
DefaultGroupName=MySetup
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MySetup.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
 Source: "D:\FirstExeFolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}\App"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
 Source: "D:\test\SecondExeFolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}\server"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
 Source: "D:\test\batinstaller.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MySetup"; Filename: "{app}\batinstaller.bat"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\icon.ico" 


[Run]
Filename: "{app}\batinstaller.bat"
```

It will compile the script into window installer that can be support in any window machine.

Answer (score 2):

If I don't misunderstand you...

This is a batch file that generates a `.Net` exe that may start as many processes as you want. Save it as (i.e *build.bat*) run it and you get a `myNetExe.exe` file that will start two `notepad`.

```
//>nul 2>nul||@goto :batch_code
/*
:batch_code
@echo off
setlocal
rem place desired exe name
set "theExeFile=myNetExe.exe"
rem if not exist "%theExeFile%" call :build_the_exe || exit/B
call :build_the_exe || exit/B

endlocal
exit /b 0

:build_the_exe
:: find csc.exe
set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /a:d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
   set netver=%%v
   goto :break_loop
)
:break_loop
set "csc=%frm%%netver%\csc.exe"
:: csc not found
if "%csc%" == "\csc.exe" echo/&echo/Warning: Net Framework Not Found&exit/B 1
::csc found
call %csc% /nologo /out:"%theExeFile%" "%~dpsfnx0" 
exit/B 0
*/

//begin c# code

using System;
using System.Security;                // get secure string
using System.Diagnostics;             // processes

namespace ElZooilogico
{

  public class Procesos
  {
    private static SecureString GetSecureString(string str)
    {
      SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
      foreach (char ch in str)
      {
        secureString.AppendChar(ch);
      }
      secureString.MakeReadOnly();
      return secureString;
    }

    //public static bool CreateProceso(string processName, string processArgs, string user, string pass, out uint processID, bool bShowWindow = true)
    public static bool CreateProceso(string processName, string processArgs, out uint processID, bool bShowWindow = true)
    {
      bool result = false;
      processID   = 0;

      try
      {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
          RedirectStandardOutput = false,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          CreateNoWindow = bShowWindow,
          //UserName = user,
          //Password = GetSecureString(pass),
          FileName = processName,
          Arguments = processArgs
        };

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

        if ( (result = p.Start()) )
          processID = (uint)p.Id;
      } catch {}
      return result;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
      uint processID = 0;
      try {
        CreateProceso("notepad", @"C:\Windows\win.ini", out processID, true);
        CreateProceso("notepad", @"C:\Windows\system.ini", out processID, true);

        //use following line to start process under other user account (remove comments from UserName/Password above)
        //CreateProceso("notepad", @"C:\Windows\win.ini", "some_user_name", "user_password", out processID, true);
      } catch {}
    }

  } // class Procesos

}
```

Change `notepad` with your `path\exe` and `C:\Windows\win.ini` to your params and that's it.

Also you may change `main` function to run programs from commandline, but then you must be sure that you always set a pair of `program + prog_params` for each program. Also, if `path` or `params` contain spaces, place quotes. Another approach would be adding checks, but is out of this scope.

ie. `myNetExe "C:\Program Files (x86)\some_folder\some.exe" "param1 param2" "C:\Program Files (x86)\some_other_folder\other.exe" ""`. In the later, there are not params, but an empty string must be sent.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  uint processID = 0;
  try {
    for ( int i = 0; i < args.Length; i+=2 )
    {
      CreateProceso(args[i], args[i+1], out processID, true);
    }
  } catch {}
}
```

**EDIT** Only as a proof of concept, added switches to create **shortcuts**.

```
//>nul 2>nul||@goto :batch_code
/*
:batch_code
@echo off
setlocal
rem place desired exe name
set "theExeFile=myNetExe.exe"
rem if not exist "%theExeFile%" call :build_the_exe || exit/B
call :build_the_exe || exit/B

endlocal
exit /b 0

:build_the_exe
:: find csc.exe
set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /a:d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
   set netver=%%v
   goto :break_loop
)
:break_loop
rem set "netver=v3.5" & rem for version build testing purposes
cls&echo/&echo/Framework version is [%netver:~1%]&echo/
set "csc=%frm%%netver%\csc.exe"
:: csc not found
if "%csc%" == "\csc.exe" echo/&echo/Warning: Net Framework Not Found&exit/B 1
::csc found
if /I "%netver%" EQU "v3.5" (
  call %csc% /nologo /define:NET35 /out:"%theExeFile%" "%~dpsfnx0" && (echo Done^!) || (echo Failed^!)
) else (
  call %csc% /nologo /define:NET40 /out:"%theExeFile%" "%~dpsfnx0" && (echo Done^!) || (echo Failed^!)
)
exit/B 0
*/



//begin c# code
using System;
using System.IO;                      // file, path
using System.Security;                // get secure string
using System.Reflection;              // Shortcut
using System.Diagnostics;             // processes
using System.Windows.Forms;           // Application
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // Com

namespace ElZooilogico
{
  public static class Shortcut
  {
    private const string DEFAULT_EXTENSION  = ".lnk";

#if (NET35)
    public static string Create(string linkFileName, string targetPath, string description, string arguments, int iconNumber)
#else
    public static string Create(string linkFileName, string targetPath, string description = "", string arguments = "", int iconNumber = 0)
#endif
    {
      if ( linkFileName.Contains(DEFAULT_EXTENSION) == false )
        linkFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", linkFileName, DEFAULT_EXTENSION);

      if ( File.Exists(targetPath) == false )
        throw new Exception(targetPath);

      string iconLocation = string.Format("{0},{1}", targetPath, iconNumber);

      Type t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("72C24DD5-D70A-438B-8A42-98424B88AFB8")); //Windows Script Host Shell Object

#if (NET35)
      object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
      try {
        object shortcut = t.InvokeMember("CreateShortcut", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[]{linkFileName});
        try {
          t.InvokeMember("TargetPath", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, shortcut, new object[]{targetPath});
          t.InvokeMember("WorkingDirectory", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, shortcut, new object[]{Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath)});
          t.InvokeMember("Arguments", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, shortcut, new object[]{arguments});
          t.InvokeMember("WindowStyle", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, shortcut, new object[]{1});
          t.InvokeMember("Description", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, shortcut, new object[]{description});
          t.InvokeMember("IconLocation", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, shortcut, new object[]{"shell32.dll, 5"});
          t.InvokeMember("Save", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shortcut, null);
        } finally { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shortcut); }
      } finally { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shell); }
#else
      dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
      try {
        var shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(linkFileName);
        try {
          shortcut.TargetPath = targetPath;
          shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath);
          shortcut.Arguments = arguments;
          shortcut.WindowStyle = 1;
          shortcut.Description = description;
          shortcut.IconLocation = "shell32.dll, 1"; //iconLocation; // "shell32.dll, 1";
          shortcut.Save();
        } finally { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shortcut); }
      } finally { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shell); }
#endif
      return Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, linkFileName);
    }

  } // class Shortcut



  public class Procesos
  {
    private static string own = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\My Shortcut";
#if (NET35)
    private static string all = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory) + @"Users\Public\Desktop\All Shortcut";
#else
    private static string all = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory) + "\\All Shortcut";
#endif

    private static SecureString GetSecureString(string str)
    {
      SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
      foreach (char ch in str)
      {
        secureString.AppendChar(ch);
      }
      secureString.MakeReadOnly();
      return secureString;
    }

    //public static bool CreateProceso(string processName, string processArgs, string user, string pass, out uint processID, bool bShowWindow = true)
#if (NET35)
    public static bool CreateProceso(string processName, string processArgs, out uint processID, bool bShowWindow)
#else
    public static bool CreateProceso(string processName, string processArgs, out uint processID, bool bShowWindow = true)
#endif
    {
      bool result = false;
      processID   = 0;

      try
      {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
          RedirectStandardOutput = false,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          CreateNoWindow = bShowWindow,
          //UserName = user,
          //Password = GetSecureString(pass),
          FileName = processName,
          Arguments = processArgs
        };

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

        if ( (result = p.Start()) )
          processID = (uint)p.Id;
      } catch {}
      return result;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      uint processID = 0;

      if ( args.Length > 0 )
      {
        try {
          for ( int i = 0; i < args.Length; i+=2 )
          {
            if ( args[i].Equals("/LO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ) { try { Shortcut.Create(own, Application.ExecutablePath, "This is a shortcut for current user", string.Empty, 0); } catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); return; } return; }
            if ( args[i].Equals("/LA", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ) { try { Shortcut.Create(all, Application.ExecutablePath, "This is a shortcut for all users", string.Empty, 0); } catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); return; } return; }
            try
            {
              CreateProceso(args[i], args[i+1], out processID, true);
            } catch {}
          }
         } catch {}
      }
      else
      {
        try {
          CreateProceso("notepad", @"C:\Windows\win.ini", out processID, true);
          CreateProceso("notepad", @"C:\Windows\system.ini", out processID, true);
          //use following line to start process under other user account (remove comments from UserName/Password above)
          //CreateProceso("notepad", @"C:\Windows\win.ini", "some_user_name", "user_password", out processID, true);
        } catch {}
      }
    }
  } // class Procesos
} // namespace ElZooilogico
```

Comment: I don't think the OP really needs a batch script per se.  But the C# code looks useful.

Comment: Thanks for all  of your efforts and it's helpful . I just put the solution that resolved this question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Added code to create shortcuts. Hope U enjoy! ;-)